# Deserialize JSON to class in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

If my string(json) contain only following part, I am able to deserialize it with the help of newtonsoft's library.

```
{"Code": "MXXXXX", "Status": "failed"}
```

Code to deserialize:

```
public class Account
{
    public string Code{ get; set; }
    public string Status{ get; set; }
}
Account account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(json);

Console.WriteLine(account.Code);
```

But if my string is like this:

```
{'data': ' {"Code": "MXXXXX", "Status": "failed"}'}
```

I am unable to deserialize. Here the class has only one property which is data... how can I do that?

Comment: Put your json string at http://jsonutils.com/ and generate required code for the type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
public class Account
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}


public class AccountWrapper
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "data")]
    public string Data { get; set; }

    public Account Account
    {
        get { return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(Data); }
    }
}

// DeserializeObject
        string data = "{'data':'{\"Code\":\"MXXXXX\",\"Status\":\"failed\"}'}";

        var account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccountWrapper>(data).Account;
```

Answer (score 4):

You will need another class for that which wraps the actual account  , like:

```
public class Account
{
    public Data Data { get; set };
}

public class Data
{
    public string Code{ get; set; }
    public string Status{ get; set; }
}

Account account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(json);

Console.WriteLine(account .Data.Code);
```

Comment: make sure both classes have an empty(parameterless) constructor

Comment: Thanks peter for ur help.But I am getting error on line where derilize.Error is 'Could not cast or convert from System.String to Data. '.Json is my string.

Answer (score 3):

You could deserialize the whole json as JObject, and then parse part of it into Account:

```
JObject wholeJson = JObject.Parse(json);
JToken dataToken = wholeJson.GetValue("data");
Account account = dataToken.ToObject<Account>();
```

Comment: Getting error at Getvalue method.Method is not visible.

Comment: @JuiTest, which version of Json.net are you using? Here is this method in the docs: [GetValue](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_GetValue.htm)

Comment: I am using 'Newtonsoft.Json.Net20.dll'

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is that, You can prepare the same object as of the json structure. Like,

```
public class Test
{
    public string data{ get; set; }        
}
```

you can get data out of the object and deserialize it as your doing it now.
Or read it in JObject and then get the data and deserialize it.